# Forcing x-axis of pyplot histogram (python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

Hi so I have a data called vc that looks like this.

It is a count of scores. The score range is from 0 to 40.

However, as shown below, there is only a few with actual counts. I can't make the histogram to have the x axis that I want..

```
d = {'count': [9, 30, 6, 2,3,1,1,4,1,1,2,2,6,3]}
vc = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26])

vc
      index   count
        12       9
        13      30
        14       6
        15       2
        17       3
        18       1
        19       1
        20       4
    ...and so on
```

I want to make a histogram with x axis from 0 to 40, like this: [histogram I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1jVZ.png)

However, my histogram doesn't show the scores with zero counts..

```
vc=vc.sort_index()
ax = vc.plot(kind='bar', legend=False)
ax.set_xlabel("score")
ax.set_ylabel("count")
ax.set_xticks(range(0,40,5))
```

The resulting histogram: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbrHf.png)

How can I produce the wanted histogram in the first image?
I've tried for hours but have sadly failed.. Thank you

Comment: `vc.reindex(range(40)).plot.bar()`?

Comment: Thanks I have tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you missing any data? @QuangHoang solution works for me, but the histogram you are looking for, has more data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a very clever solution, but you can plot a blank with the range you need, then plot over with your count table:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

d = {'count': [9, 30, 6, 2,3,1,1,4,1,1,2,2,6,3]}
vc = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26])
plt.bar(x=np.arange(10,40),height=0)
plt.bar(vc.index.to_list(),vc['count'])
```

[image]